# Appending to Arrays and Sampling in R-Lang

Tags: arrays, vector, sample

I am trying to append value to two separate arrays.

I would like to then append these arrays to a multi-dimensional array for a weighted sample. My arrays are not populating and I have a feeling my multi-dimensional array is also not going to work.

```
# Functions make life easier
put_the_marble_in_the_bag <- function(m, B){
    B <- c(B, m)
}

colour_me_marbles <- function(x,n,B,b){
    a = list("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f")
    for(i in a[1:n]){
    q <- paste(x,"_",b,toString(i), sep = "")
    # print(q) # debug
    B <- put_the_marble_in_the_bag(q,B)
    }
}

#declare empty arrays
B_1=B_2=c()

# Bag 1 contains:
# - 7 white marbles
# - 6 black marbles
# - 3 gold marbles

colour_me_marbles("w",7,B_1,1)
colour_me_marbles("l",6,B_1,1)
colour_me_marbles("g",3,B_1,1)

# Bag 2 contains:
# - 4 white marbles
# - 5 black marbles
# - 15 gold marbles

colour_me_marbles("w",4,B_2,2)
colour_me_marbles("l",5,B_2,2)
colour_me_marbles("g",15,B_2,2)

# Why is this empty?
# print(B_1) # debug
# print(B_2) # debug

# I want to sample a multi-dimensional array
# Where the likelihood of drawing from B_1 is 2/3
# and the likelihood of drawing from B_2 is 1/3

sample(c(B_1, B_2), size=1000 ,replace = TRUE, prob = c(2/3, 1/3))
```